# How to drop duplicate rows based on values of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, row, data-science, drop-duplicates

I have a data frame like this:

```
Category Date_1       Score_1    Date_2           Score_2
  A      13/11/2019    5        13/11/2019        10
  A      13/11/2019    5        14/11/2019        55
  A      13/11/2019    5        15/11/2019        45
  A      13/11/2019    5        16/11/2019        80
  A      14/11/2019    3        13/11/2019        10
  A      14/11/2019    3        14/11/2019        55
  A      14/11/2019    3        15/11/2019        45
  A      14/11/2019    3        16/11/2019        80
  A      15/11/2019    7        13/11/2019        10
  A      15/11/2019    7        14/11/2019        55
  A      15/11/2019    7        15/11/2019        45
  A      15/11/2019    7        16/11/2019        80
  B      13/11/2019    4        13/11/2019        18
  B      13/11/2019    4        14/11/2019        65
  B      13/11/2019    4        15/11/2019        75
  B      13/11/2019    4        16/11/2019        89
  B      14/11/2019    9        13/11/2019        18
  B      14/11/2019    9        14/11/2019        65
  B      14/11/2019    9        15/11/2019        75
  B      14/11/2019    9        16/11/2019        89
  B      15/11/2019    8        13/11/2019        18
  B      15/11/2019    8        14/11/2019        65
  B      15/11/2019    8        15/11/2019        75
  B      15/11/2019    8        16/11/2019        89
```

I want to keep the rows where both dates are same. 
I  was doing this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date_1', 'Date_2'])
```

But it do not work. Can`t figure out how to drop those extra rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare both columns:

```
df1 = df[df['Date_1'] == df['Date_2'])
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Date_1 == Date_2")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated` with the parameter `subset` for specifying columns to be checked with `keep=False`, for all duplicates for masking and filtering by boolean indexing. The following should work:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Date_1', 'Date_2'], keep=False)]
```

**Remark:** Initially, I may have misread that OP wanted to drop duplicates, with answers below:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date_1', 'Date_2'], keep='last')
```

You should always assign the `df` back like above to apply the changes. Otherwise you can add `inplace=True` to apply the changes without assignment:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date_1', 'Date_2'], keep='last', inplace=True)
```

If this doesn't work as well as the solutions provided by others, you may want to check whether there is any difference in data types for those columns which are in `subset`, for example datetime formatting.

Comment: Actually, that answer does not answer asked question, as it does not  "keep the rows where both dates are same."

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod Thanks for pointing that out. Initially I misread that OP wanted to drop duplicates. Give me a sec, I'll update the answer.